# Docker OSX disc storage

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am using the latest docker 1.8.2 on Mac OSX 10.10.5
I am running out of disc space during a build.  Current docs point to https://docs.docker.com/articles/b2d_volume_resize/ but there is no boot2docker binary with this release.

I tried to add a ~/./boot2docker/profile with a DiskSize but not sure how to force docker to read it.

Thanks.
Pat.

Answer (score 3):

Few weeks ago Docker-Toolbox was released (see [Announcement on Docker Blog](https://blog.docker.com/2015/08/docker-toolbox/)). With this the Boot2docker cli was removed and docker-machine was added instead. Boot2docker is now "only" the VM.

Things are going to get a little bit easier with docker-machine. Having said that, you best install the latest version of Docker-Toolbox first. This gives you not only docker-machine, but also all the other docker tools. In case you like to manually upgrade your Boot2docker based installation to Toolbox, the above referenced Announcement links the Docker Toolbox website for additional information.

Back to your problem. With docker-machine you need to create a new "machine" which is in your case a Boot2docker based VM for VirtualBox. The command used for this is `docker-machine create`. This command has several options. One of it is `--virtualbox-disk-size`. With this you specify how large your VM can get.

Here is an example I use to create a new machine, which is called *default*: `docker-machine create --driver=virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size 35000 --virtualbox-cpu-count 2 --virtualbox-memory 2048 default`. The machine *default* has a virtual disk of size 35GB, 2GB RAM and uses up to 2 Cores.

By the way, this also means that the data from your previous Boot2docker VM is not available in the new machine. There is another option for `docker-machine create` which is called `--virtualbox-import-boot2docker-vm`. According to the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/virtualbox/) this let's you import your previous Boot2docker VM. However, in contrast to the previous solution (creating a brand new VM), I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: I had the similar problems with my docker installation on Mac (unable to build and even unable to start a docker due to running out of disk space). After deleting existing docker using 'docker-machine rm default' and re-creating new default using example provided in this answer the problem was solved.